# My css first-child pseudo-selector is working in reverse manner

Tags: css, css-selectors

The syntax of selecting first child in `<ul>` list is:

```css
li: first-child{color:blue;}
```

but it is not working.
Instead when I write it in reverse manner like:

```css
ul: first-child{color:blue;}
```

then it is working properly. Is it right or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set `:first-child` with li without space.

`li:first-child{color:blue;}`

The other way is also right because you are setting the first child of the elements inside of ul. ul follow with space means selects all elements inside `<ul>` elements

`ul :first-child{color:blue;}`

You may refer to w3schools [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) for details.

```css
/* Both setting the same li to blue */
li:first-child{color:blue;}
ul :first-child{color:blue;}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> Item 1 </li>
  <li> Item 2 </li>
  <li> Item 3 </li>
</ul>
```